# What is the equivalent function in openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlrd, xlwt

In xlrd and xlwt to append the rows of a sheet to an array I can do:

```
Stuff = []

column_count = sheet.ncols - 1

for i in range (0, column_count):
     Stuff.append([sheet.cell_value(row, i) for row in range(sheet.nrows)])
```

**How do I do the equivalent in openpyxl?**

Comment: What is it you want to do?

Comment: Append everything from one sheet to another sheet

Comment: Please edit the question to illustrate more clearly what you want to do. Looping through one worksheet and copying the cell values to another is easy to do in openpyxl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through the rows of a worksheet:

```
stuff = [[cell.value for cell in row] for row in sheet]
```

Or, if you rather group it by columns, use `.columns`:

```
stuff = [[cell.value for cell in column] for column in sheet.columns]
```

The columns property is not available for read-only worksheets because data is stored in rows.

Comment: how would I append that array to an excel document in openpyxl?

Comment: @nickm there is that `sheet.append()` method that might help you to do it easily. It would append an array of values to the end of the sheet. Try it out. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, sheets are directly iterable and openpyxl 2.4 also provides a `.values` property. `for row in sheet` or `for row in sheet.values`

Comment: @CharlieClark ah yeah, that would be much simpler, thanks.

Comment: When I add sheet.append(stuff) it says that it can't convert the headers to excel

Comment: @nickm okay, please see if it makes sense to create a separate question if you need help. Thanks!

Comment: Yea I got it, you have to have a for loop